# How can I create slider layout with css flex boxes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, slider, alignment

I'm trying to create a Slider Layout with flex boxes, like this photo :

[image]

Here I've big photo at right side and thumbnail items on the left. I want to align left side and thumbnails wrapper with big photo height. But unfortunately It's not possible only with flex boxes and I should check big photo height with JavaScript and align left side with that.

For example check this code:

```css
main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

.right{
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    height: 450px;
    background: red;
}

.left{
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

In sample code I've not image and I handled this issue with 450px height in CSS.

So how can I align the left side with out JS and only with CSS? I want to use `space-between` mode to show all items in this height. Consider it, `height:100%` didn't work for this issue.

Comment: are you wanting so the thumbnails fill the left column? (I cannot see the image due to firewall restrictions)  If so, just remove `align-items: flex-start;` from your wrapper

Comment: really ? you can't open picofile.com ? I'm Iranian and I can upload photos only on this provider. flex-start didn't work. because it's comfortable when I want to show th images from top to left. but I want to arrange all th files on left side height

Comment: @Pete new demo link: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/25/cc9c736bc153a0eccaf918fd3fc95f7a-full.jpg

Comment: Yeah work firewall blocks all file sharing sites unfortunately, that second link looks like what I thought you meant - have you tried removing flex start from the wrapper?

Comment: I've added the image inline. @Pete hopefully you'll be able to see it in the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, in order for your left column to extend to the height of your right column, all you need to do is remove the align items from your wrapper:

```css
main{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    /* align-items: flex-start; -- remove this */ 
    justify-content: center;
}

.right{
    /* width: calc(100% - 150px);  I would swap this for flex grow, then you don't need hard values */
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 450px;
    background: red;
}

.left{
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <strong>Item</strong>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [**`CSS Grid layouts`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) - use `display: grid` on your `wrapper` that lays out your `left` and `right` sections using `grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr` (remove the `width` definitions in `right` and `left` elements.).

Now add `height: 100%` to `left` and then for the items `flex: 1` for the *flexbox items* to occupy the dynamic height coming from the `right` section - see demo below:

```css
main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  display: grid; /* make this a grid container */
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr; /* 150px for left and rest for right*/
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  /* width: calc(100% - 150px);*/
  height: 450px;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  /*width: 150px;*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; /* ADDED */
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="item">
        <strong>Item</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <strong>Item</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <strong>Item</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <strong>Item</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <strong>Item</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I'm not familiar with css grid layouts. Apparently it's not possible with only css flex-boxes and I should use JS to manage left side height

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be done with flexbox, if you set the height of the container to be the height you want all your sliders to be:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.container > * {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.thumbs {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.thumb {
  background: red;
  flex: 1 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.large {
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumbs">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="large"></div>
</div>
```